# How to access MathJax extensions (like siunitx) from Rmarkdown via Pandoc & Knitr?

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc, mathjax

Working with `Rmarkdown` in `Rstudio`, using `pandoc` and `knitr`, I am targetting PDF output via LaTeX and HTML output with `MathJax`. I would like to use some of the `MathJax` extensions that are available, to allow richer LaTeX for the PDF target. Specifically, I am trying to use the `siunitx` extension right now, although I am also interested in others (e.g. `physics`).

Using `siunitx` works fine with LaTeX for PDF output, but I've had a hard time getting it working with HTML output.

Here an example Rmarkdown file:

````
---
title: "siunitx test"
author: "chriss"
date: "June 13, 2017"
output:
  html_document:
    mathjax: https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML
    number_sections: yes
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
    number_sections: yes
header-includes: \usepackage{siunitx}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# The Problem

I would like to be able to use `siunitx` latex macros from `Rmarkdown`,
targetting PDF output via latex and html with MathJax. It should get me proper
formatting of things like $\SI{120}{\W\per\square\m}$ and $\SI{0.8}{\A\per\W}$,
as long as I put them in a latex math environment, so that MathJax picks them
up.

The PDF output is OK when I add the `header-includes: \usepackage{siunitx}` to
the `YAML` header, but how can I access the MathJax `siunitx` extension via the
knitr -> pandoc -> mathjax/html route?

Check: is MathJax working in general: $\frac{1}{r^2}$
````

This knits fine to PDF, but the `$\SI{}{}$` are output verbatim and hilighted red in the HTML output, and in `RStudio`. I'm having `pandoc` get `MathJax` from `rawgit.org`, since the default of `cdn.mathjax.org` is soon-to-be defunct, and it seems, no longer has a `Contrib` path with the extensions.

I have tried adding `MathJax`'s `$\require{siunitx}$` with variations on the path to the `siunitx` extension, to no avail. This causes the HTML to look for the `siunitx` extension, but apparently in the wrong place: `https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/extensions/TeX/siunitx.js?V=2.7.1`, which is a `404`.

If I remove the `\require{}` and remove the part of the output HTML file that loads `MathJax` dynamically (labelled `<!-- dynamically load mathjax for compatibility with self-contained -->`), and manually add:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"],["\\(","\\)"]]},
  errorSettings: {message: undefined},
    TeX: { extensions: ["[burnpanck]/siunitx/unpacked/siunitx.js"] }
  };
  MathJax.Ajax.config.path['burnpanck']  = 
'https://rawgit.com/burnpanck/MathJax-third-party-extensions/master';
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mathjax/MathJax/2.7.1/latest.js?config=TeX-AMS-
MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

To header of the HTML file, then it briefly pops up a complaint about some issue with `siunitx.js` but produces correct output (this is a modified version of the header from the example for the `siunitx` MathJax extension, from [here](https://github.com/burnpanck/MathJax-third-party-extensions/blob/add-siunitx-tex-extension/siunitx/sample-siunitx.html) )

This suggests that I could modify the HTML template for `pandoc` to reflect those changes, and things would basically work.

However, the following questions remain:

- Is changing the HTML template in this way the proper way to fix the HTML output? Are these the URLs that are intended to be used now that `cdn.mathjax.org` is going down, or are there better ones that I should use instead?
- Why do I still get the warning about `siunitx.js`?
- What would need to be done to have `Rstudio` understand the `siunitx` content in its preview? Is there already a way to enable this (e.g. convince it to use `siunitx` extension, assuming it's built on `MathJax`), or would this be a feature request..?

Indeed, it would be nice if there was an easy way to access the `MathJax` extensions out-of-the-box, without having to go to the trouble of editing templates and the like, with proper handling in the `Rstudio` GUI. I can imagine there may be `Rstudio` users who would benefit from the extra functionality but don't want to / aren't able to jump through these kind of hoops to access it.

**UPDATE** The warning message I see when loading the 'working' HTML about `siunitx.js` seems to be a general issue with the current version of `siunitx.js`, due to changes to the MathJax CDN, see issue raised here: https://github.com/burnpanck/MathJax-third-party-extensions/issues/5

Comment: You might want to add a live example that shows the "warning" you describe so people can see what you see.

Comment: The "warning" seems to be a general issue with the current version of the `siunitx` package, due to MathJax CDN issues; see issue here: https://github.com/burnpanck/MathJax-third-party-extensions/issues/5

Comment: Thanks for linking to the bug report. I've commented there. I can't comment on rstudio but (from the MathJax end) the main reason why this is hard  is that siunitx is a third party extension and not part of the core.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using includes in_header to solve the problem.

```
---
title: "doku1"
output:
  html_document:
    includes:
     in_header: header.html
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
    number_sections: no
header-includes: \usepackage{mhchem, siunitx}
---
```

header.html looks like this

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Ajax.config.path["mhchem"] = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax-mhchem/3.3.2";
MathJax.Ajax.config.path['myExt']  = 'https://rawgit.com/burnpanck/MathJax-third-party-extensions/master';
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  TeX: { extensions: ["AMSmath.js","AMSsymbols.js","[myExt]/siunitx/unpacked/siunitx.js","[mhchem]/mhchem.js", "color.js"] }
  });
</script>
```

It works, but is rather slow.

John