# How to extend RStudio MathJax to include extensions in "live" notebooks?

Tags: rstudio, mathjax

One of the answers to the StackOverflow question below gives a way of knitting an html page which can use mhchem.js to typeset basic chemistry notation.

[How to access MathJax extensions (like siunitx) from Rmarkdown via Pandoc & Knitr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44521381/how-to-access-mathjax-extensions-like-siunitx-from-rmarkdown-via-pandoc-knit)

How can I modify RStudio MathJax to make this rendering happen live in the edited document? Preferably, this extension would just be enabled for all RStudio notebook files for all users of the RStudio Server installation. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

I found out this is already built-in once I tell it the magic word:

```
$$
\require{mhchem}
\ce{H + H -> H_2}
$$
```

See the MathJax docs:

http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/extensions/mhchem.html